# How to insert into sql table while VSTS load test is also inserting

Tags: visual-studio-2008, load-testing

I need to track custom information  associated with each request URI during 'load test' run.

I know that VSTS stores 'requestURI' in table called 'WebLoadTestRequestMap'.

Could some one tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add your own new table to the database (with LoadTestRunId as a foreign key) and insert your custom information into that table in the PostRequest event.

There is no way to alter the automatic behaviour of the load test engine when it adds data to the load test database.